# Split a stereo stream into two mono streams

Tags: c, stream, split, fmod

I've been using Fmod (c/c++) for a few days and I was wondering if there was a way to split a single stereo stream (left/right) into two mono streams and thus have them in two channels instead of one channel (in order to have two separate volumes and pans) ? Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

One way I know is if you create two channel on one sound and then
use `channel.setInputChannelMix({0, 1}, 1)` for controlling audio to channel